# fails to redirect the output into file

Tags: c++, io-redirection

I have a sample code which print some log information but it fails to output the log information into files ( `executable > logfile.txt` or `executable > logfile.txt 2>&1` ) during program running. But if the program finish, the log can be outputted into file. In real code, there is a large loop and I want to redirect the print info into files and check the information during the program running.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{

    std::cout << "Starting program\n";    
    //int count = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout <<"thread running\n";
        usleep(1000000);
        //count++;
        //if(count>3){
        //    break;
        //}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know how to redirect the information printed in program to files

Comment: If you're on a Linux box, try [man unbuffer](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) to learn how to use the `unbuffer` program to disable buffering. You may need to install a package called "expect".

Comment: It works to use unbuffer of expect, thanks a lot for your help. I'm curious about the reason for this.

Comment: Try to change `std::cout << "thread running\n"` to `std::cout << "thread running" << std::endl`.

Comment: Thanks, it works when i use std::endl, it seems that using std::endl could avoid the IO buffer here?